# How to write a program that analyzes strings, identifies the hashtags, counts them and adds them to a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

sample input

```
[
    "hi #weekend",
    "good morning #madrid #fun",
    "spend my #weekend in #madrid",
    "#madrid <3"
]
```

expected output

```
{'weekend': 2, 'madrid': 3, 'fun': 1}
```

Rules:

- the program shouldn't consider an empty hashtag ("#") as one
- hashtags not starting with a letter shouldn't be considered hashtags
- it should consider lower and upper case hashtags as different hashtags

---

This is what I have so far. My goal is to include the rules in the program

```
from collections import Counter

def analyze(posts):
    counter = Counter(
        x[1:] for x in ' '.join(posts).split() if x.startswith('#')
    )
    return dict(counter)


posts = [
    "hi #weekend",
    "good morning #madrid #fun",
    "spend my #weekend in #madrid",
    "#madrid <3"]

print(analyze(posts))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the condition that the hashtag should start with a letter I suggest using regex to extract all hashtags [starting with a letter](https://regexr.com/68jn3):

```
import re
from collections import Counter

def analyze(posts):
    hits = re.findall('#[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]*', ' '.join(data))
    return Counter([i[1:] for i in hits])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = [
    "hi #weekend",
    "good morning #madrid #fun",
    "spend my #weekend in #madrid",
    "#madrid <3"
]

my_dict = {}

for j in a:
    for i in j.split():
        if i.startswith("#") and i[1].isalpha():
            if i[1:] in my_dict:
                my_dict[i[1:]] += 1
            else:
                my_dict[i[1:]] = 1
print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'weekend': 2, 'madrid': 3, 'fun': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.Counter` and a simple comprehension:

```
l = [
    "hi #weekend",
    "good morning #madrid #fun",
    "spend my #weekend in #madrid",
    "#madrid <3"
]

from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(w[1:] for w in ' '.join(l).split()
                 if len(w)>1 and w.startswith('#') and w[1].isalpha())
```

output:

```
>>> counts
Counter({'weekend': 2, 'madrid': 3, 'fun': 1})

# as dictionary
>>> dict(counts)
{'weekend': 2, 'madrid': 3, 'fun': 1}
```

Comment: This will include hashtags starting with a number...

Comment: @RJAdriaansen I just saw the condition and provided an update ;)